# How to call a `dyn Fn` which is a field?

Tags: rust

```
struct DummyRtspClient<'a> {
    on_produce: &'a dyn Fn(EncodedPacket)
}

impl ... for DummyRtspClient {
    fn set_on_produce(&self, f: &'a dyn Fn(EncodedPacket)){
        self.on_produce = f;
    }
}
```

Then how can I use `on_produce`?

I tried

```
let encoded_packet = EncodedPacket{
    data: Vec::new(),
};
self.on_produce(encoded_packet);
```

but it says that `on_produce` is not a member function, but a field.

I tried `self.on_produce.call(encoded_packet)` but I also get errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error message should say something like this:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `on_produce` found for reference `&DummyRtspClient<'a>` in the current scope
  --> src/lib.rs:14:18
   |
14 |             self.on_produce(encoded_packet);
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^ field, not a method
   |
help: to call the function stored in `on_produce`, surround the field access with parentheses
   |
14 |             (self.on_produce)(encoded_packet);
   |             ^               ^
```

In particular, the second part tells exactly you how to solve this: wrap `self.on_produce` in a set of parentheses to disambiguate it from attempting to call a member function.

Comment: I was using intellisense which doe snot display the entire suggestion. Thanks!